# How to make text reveal animation on button hover in CSS?

Tags: html, css

**Hi all,**

I'm trying to make an opening animation on a *button hover*, but the to be revealed text jumps into *two lines* until the animation is finished. I could change the button text and the width animation works great, but the nex text completely messes it up. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<button id="button_closed"><span>+</span></button>
```

**CSS**

```
#button_closed {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background:    #00ff00;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color:         #ffffff;
    font:          normal bold 22px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    text-align:    center;
}

#button_closed:hover span {
    display: none;
}

#button_closed:hover {
    width: 180px;
    transition: width 1s;
}

#button_closed:hover::after {
    content: "New Project";
}
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could share a solution or a working tutorial. **Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Have you tried `#button_closed:hover span::after { content: "New Project";}` and delete `#button_closed:hover span` plus you need to add a transition in your `#button_closed` for the width.

Comment: Doesn't work :(
Thansk tho, I fixed the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add those to your button's CSS:

```
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
#button_closed {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background:    #00ff00;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color:         #ffffff;
    font:          normal bold 22px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    text-align:    center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#button_closed:hover span {
    display: none;
}

#button_closed:hover {
    width: 180px;
    transition: width 1s;
}

#button_closed::after {
  content: "";
  width: 160px;
  display: none;
}

#button_closed:hover::after {
    content: "New Project";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="button_closed"><span>+</span></button>
```